# Como chamar uma nova Activity através de uma estrutura condicional que testa a conexão?

Tags: android, webview, intent

Estou fazendo uma app de WebView. É bem simples: testo a conexão caso verdade carrega o site; caso falso carrega outra activity (que não a main).

Enquanto há conexão, a app funciona certinho, carregando o site. Porém quando não há conexão ele retorna o erro comum a qualquer navegador, quando era pra retornar minha segunda activity que diz que o aparelho esta sem internet.

Aqui vai o código da minha MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView wv;
    String URL = "http://www.google.com";

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(wv.canGoBack() ){
            wv.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if(cm == null) {
            return false;
        } else
            return true;

    }

    public void notConnected(){
        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, connectionErrorActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(isOnline()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);

            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.setFocusable(true);
            wv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
            wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

            wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadStart(String URL, String userAgent, String contentDisposition,
                                            String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(URL));

                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Boletos RNet");
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fazendo Download", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            wv.loadUrl(URL);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        }else {
            notConnected();
        }
    }
}
```

Como é possível observar, caso sem conexão é chamado um metodo que implementa uma Intent que por sua vez deveria chamar `ConnectionErrorActivity.class`. Mas isso nao acontece. Alguém me de uma luz?

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema é que seu método `isOnline()` não funciona. Ele sempre retorna `true`.

Experimente esse aqui:

```
public static boolean isOnline() {

    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas não deu certo... agora realmente ele entrou no "else" do teste de conexão, mas não carregou a segunda activity, ao inves disso começou a da um erro.
Talvez minha segunda activity esteja errada?! - 

public class connectionErrorActivity extends MainActivity {
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection_error);
    }
}

Comment: Provavelmente o problema é na outra. Qual é a mensagem de erro no LogCat?

Comment: Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/_boost_: new PerfServiceWrapper
D/_boost_: startActivityForResult boost 2500
E/MultiWindowProxy: getServiceInstance failed!

... a app nao fecha no celular e no log fica repetindo esse erro

Comment: Acho melhor você abrir uma nova pergunta, colocar o código só da outra Activity e o log completo porque estamos fugindo do escopo dessa.